# class GameViewController has no initializers swift2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Here is my code. Adding the `!` mark doesn't do anything.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var banner: GADBannerView!

    var interstital: GADInterstitial

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // other code
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `interstital` actually used? What line is the error on? What's the full error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
var interstital: GADInterstitial
```

To this:

```
var interstital: GADInterstitial!
```

Comment: thank you so much for the advice it worked, i put the ! mark in the wrong place.

Comment: @user6794475 No prob. If you could kindly mark the answer as correct